# Some packages in python site-packages are not displayed

Tags: python, pip, package

[image: Python package list]

These are the list of packages that are presented in my machine. When I tried to use the following python command to get the list the packages with its version, I was only able to see the packages **jinja,jsonschema,markupsafe and matplotlib** and the package **"isapi"** is missing.

```
>>> import pip
>>> ["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.utils.pkg_resources.working_set]
```

**Result / Output:**

```
['jinja2==2.7.3', 'jsonschema==2.5.1', 'markupsafe==0.23', 'matplotlib==1.4.3']
```

My requirement is to get that (**"isapi"**) in the list too. Is there any option available ? Please provide your suggestions here.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 8):

`isapi` is [not a PyPI package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isapi) and was not installed with pip. You can see this since there is no folder for the package name with a `.dist-info` suffix.

The `.dist-info` folders<sup>1</sup> are created by pip as part of the install process to store the meta information about the PyPI package. They essentially contain all the information about a package you can also find on the PyPI website. Next to those folders, pip will then add one for the actual package with the real package name<sup>2</sup> that contains the real Python modules.

Since your `isapi` folder obviously did not come from a PyPI package, it came from another source. This could be for example an external setup utility that just installs the folder in there. It’s also possible that a different PyPI package installed the folder along as a dependency (not the case for your packages though). I suggest looking into the folder and the Python modules to get an idea what it does and where it could come from.

Anyway, since it was not installed with pip, pip obviously does not know about it. So it does not appear in the package list.

Unfortunately, there is no other good way to find out about that module programmatically. One possible way would be to simply get a directory listing of the `site-packages` folder and work through the modules that way. You could also use the [`pkgutil` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) to get a list of *all* modules (including built-in modules) and filter those out that are in the `site-packages` folder. But other than that, there is no other “registy” or something that will keep track of what is in that folder. And if you think about it, there can’t be one since you could always just drop a new folder in there on your own.

---

*Foot notes*:

<sup>1</sup> `.dist-info` folders were invented with [PEP 376](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0376/) as a way to unify the way distributions are managed.

<sup>2</sup> Python packages are not required to be spelled exactly like PyPI packages. This allows for custom casing in the names for PyPI packages (since Python packages should be lower case), or even different names. For example, the PyPI package name for Beautiful Soup 4 is [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4), but the Python package is just called `bs4`.

Comment: Thanks @poke. I have folders **adodbapi** and **zmq** (which are PyPI modules), is there any option available to display this ? What's the use of .dist-info folder ?

Comment: Also could you please tell me, is there any option available (other than **"pip"**) to display the list of packages. Please share your comments here..

Comment: The `.dist-info` folder contains all the meta information about a PyPI package, essentially everything the PyPI website displays. pip essentially adds one `<package>.dist-info` folder that contains the information about the PyPI package, and one folder that contains the module. The safest way to display the packages that are available from the `site-packages` folder is probably to get a directory listing of it and filter out the `.dist-info` folders. There is no other “registry” that is used by all installers to provide the information in a central way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pkgutil
[p[1] for p in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
```

Should give you names of all installed packages.